# Converting a DATE to DATE in UTC time : sys_extract_utc behaving differently for sysdate and systimestamp

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select sysdate from dual;    
15-NOV-2018 23:09:31

select cast(sysdate as TIMESTAMP) from dual;
15-NOV-18 11.07.47.000000000 PM

select sys_extract_utc(cast(sysdate as TIMESTAMP)) from dual;
15-NOV-18 05.40.35.000000000 PM
```

But,

```
select systimestamp from dual;
15-NOV-18 11.11.16.345959000 PM -08:00

select sys_extract_utc(systimestamp) from dual;
16-NOV-18 07.08.49.772214000 AM
```

Further,

```
select cast(sysdate as TIMESTAMP) at time zone 'UTC' from dual;
15-NOV-18 05.48.11.000000000 PM UTC
```

Why is `sys_extract_utc(cast(sysdate as TIMESTAMP))` different than `sys_extract_utc(systimestamp)` in my db?

 The time given by `sys_extract_utc(systimestamp)` is the correct UTC time, btw.

 My core requirement is converting data from a table with a DATE column to "DATE in UTC time zone" in a select query. It is of course not working (with either `sys_extract_utc` or with `at time zone 'UTC'`), which is probably because of the same reason the above conversion with sysdate is not working.

In case it helps, dbtimezone is:

```
SELECT DBTIMEZONE FROM DUAL;
+00:00
```

Comment: return type of  `systimestamp`  is `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` `SYS_EXTRACT_UTC` can only extract from a proper `timestamp with time zone` that has a time zone offset  (`-08:00`) or region name. `DATE` type cast to a `TIMESTAMP` doesn't have that information.

Comment: Any idea how to convert the date in my select query to <date in UTC> ?

Comment: I need convert a column of DATE datatype of a table, not sysdate/systimestamp

Comment: How do you know what time zone the date values in your table are nominally in? You convert to UTC from some other tome zone - so do you know you can safely assume which zone you're coming *from*?

Comment: I know that the date values in the table are in the time zone the db server is in.Ex, they are inserted as INSERT INTO ... SYSDATE. The data upload is out of my control, so changing them at the time of insertion is out of question.

Comment: Pardon me .. second arg  `tz_offset(dbtimezone)` part in my comment  is not correct . Refer Wernfried's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function `SYS_EXTRACT_UTC` works only with `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` or `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` values. `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` do not contain any time zone information, so `SYS_EXTRACT_UTC` is basically useless on `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` values.

When you run

```
SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(CAST(SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP))
```

then Oracle performs an implicit cast and actually runs

```
SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(FROM_TZ(CAST(SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP), SESSIONTIMEZONE))
```

`SYSDATE` and `SYSTIMESTAMP` returns time in time zone of database server's operating system (**NOT** `DBTIMEZONE`) whereas your command uses the current session `SESSIONTIMEZONE`

If you insist to use a `DATE` value then you could use this one:

```
SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(FROM_TZ(CAST(SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP), TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'tzr')))
```

`TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'tzr')` provides you the  time zone of database server's operating system.

Just a note, very often the time zone of database server's operating system is not a region like `Europe/Zurich` but altering twice a year between `+01:00` and `+02:00` due to daylight saving times. For `SYSDATE` and `SYSTIMESTAMP` this does not matter because the **current** UTC offset is always correct. But for example, if my table contains a DATE value `2018-08-01 12:00:00` then you will get wrong result if you run query from above today in November.

If your database server utilize daylight saving times then better use a query like

```
SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(FROM_TZ(CAST({arbitrary DATE value} AS TIMESTAMP), 'Europe/Zurich'))
```